# disabling automatic simplification in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, simplification

i want to disable automatic simplification in sympy, for example solving the equation `x*y-x` i want to get `x/x` instead of `1`

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x,y,z
expr = x*y-x
sympy.solve(expr,y)
=> 1 # i want unsimplified x/x instead of 1
```

From the sympy manual, i found UnevaluatedExpr for this purpose, but it returns empty list for the example given

```
from sympy import UnevaluatedExpr
expr1 = UnevaluatedExpr(x)*UnevaluatedExpr(y)-UnevaluatedExpr(x)
sympy.solve(expr1,y) 
=> []
```

my question is

- what is wrong with the example given?
- how can i keep expressions not-evaluated/not-simplified?

Answer (score 8):

A simpler way to disable automatic evaluation is to use [context manager   evaluate](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/3099b707e45f5abce01045de39415ee961eb09d5/sympy/core/evaluate.py#L19). For example,

```
from sympy.core.evaluate import evaluate
from sympy.abc import x,y,z
with evaluate(False):
    print(x/x)
```

This prints `1/x * x` instead of 1

However, as the docstring of the context manager says, most of SymPy code expects automatic evaluation. Anything beyond straightforward calculations is likely to break down when automatic evaluation is disabled. This happens for `solve`, even for simple equations. You can disable evaluation (either with `evaluate(False)` or by using `UnevaluatedExpr`), but you probably will not get a solution.

A partial workaround for the specific equation is to use `Dummy("x")` instead of `UnevaluateExpr(x)`. The dummy symbols are  treated as distinct even if they have the same names, so they will not cancel out.

```
>>> expr = Dummy("x")*y - Dummy("x")
>>> solve(expr, y)
[_x/_x]
```