# how to stop sympy from simplifying an expression?

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

When I am writing the probability density function for a normal distribution in Sympy (v. 1.5.1) like this:

`pdf_normal = (1 / (sigma*sqrt(2*pi))) * exp(-(1/2) * ((x - mu)/sigma)**2)`

based on an expression of the equation like this (Wikipedia):

[image]

sympy 'simplifies' the expression but makes it much harder to read:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this?

(This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839611/disabling-automatic-simplification-in-sympy) is not helping, because the proposed answer is not touching the expression at all)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `evaluate=False` to control this but it will likely end up being evaluated in subsequent operations:

```
In [11]: Pow(Mul(sigma, sqrt(2*pi, evaluate=False), evaluate=False), -1, evaluate=False)                                          
Out[11]: 
    1    
─────────
    _____
σ⋅╲╱ 2⋅π
```

Comment: Thanks, and additionally to the point you raise (evaluation in subsequent operations), I count for 4 mathematical signs 3 times 'evaluate=False'-Rolling this out for the whole equation seems not like a good idea. But it would be great if one could use one bracket for the whole thing and mark it with 'evaluate=False'

Answer (score 0):

Does symbol-trickery work for you?

```
>>> r2pi = Symbol('\\sqrt{2 \\pi}')
>>> (1 / (sigma*r2pi)) * exp(-(1/2) * ((x - mu)/sigma)**2)
```

[image: latex]

Comment: Thanks, but this makes the code less readable and the representation of the equation is only slightly more readable. If I would do this with all parts of the equation, the code would be quite unpleasant, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The `UnevaluatedExpr` class will keep an expression from being re-evaluated during subsequent operations. With the changes [suggested here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19435) I think it would solve your problem:

```
>>> from sympy import S
>>> from sympy.abc import *
>>> from sympy import S
>>> usqrt = lambda x: UnevaluatedExpr(sqrt(x, evaluate=False))
>>> (1 / (sigma*usqrt(2*pi))) * exp(((x - mu)/sigma)**2/-2)
exp(-(-mu + x)**2/(2*sigma**2))/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))
```